# Any guidance on converting Time Domain to Frequency Domain in Matlab

Tags: fft, time-domain

Below is the graph of my load cell readings at 3 samples per second. I have collected 500 such samples. I want to stabilize the readings and read that first approach is to convert time domain data to frequency domain. I am new to DSP, so i seek your expert guidance on this.

My main aim is to stabilize the readings so that i can increase an accuracy of my measuring device.[image]

Graph after fft is as shown below
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you wanna convert time domain to frequency domain, try the example here. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/fft-for-spectral-analysis.html

If you wanna stabilize your signals (maybe you should define/understand the properties of noises and signals), kalman filters are commonly utilized tool.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/kalman-filter-design.html

Comment: Great link. Thanks for that. I have another question in the code it is mentioned `Y = fft(y,251);` Why the author has taken 251 ? Any special reason?

Comment: @Nimit. The author used Y = fft(y,251) because the 'y' sequence has 251 samples. The author could just as well have used Y = fft(y).

Comment: @RichardLyons Ok thanks... Let me do fft and post the graph... After fft graph i think i should get my signal frequency..

Comment: @RichardLyons I have edited my question and uploaded the graph... Matlab code for fft is `Y = fft(y,500);
Pyy = Y.*conj(Y)/500;
f = 3/500*(0:127);
plot(f,Pyy(1:128))
title('Power spectral density')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')`

Comment: Please describe in more detail the goal of your application and what exactly you mean by "stabilize." What's your expected result and how is it different from what you are currently getting? I have a feeling that frequency domain is probably not the best choice here.

Comment: @Nimit. Your 'y' signal is riding on a VERY large DC bias. You need to use 'y = y-mean(y);' to remove the 'y' signal's DC bias before you perform your FFT.

Comment: @RichardLyons Well said. Just read the article telling to remove dc bias and then do fft. I will try again and get back..

Comment: @RichardLyons I have done as you said y = y - mean(y) and plotted the power spectrum. I can see many peaks.. Which is the desired signal in these peaks ?

Comment: @Nimit.Please send me a private e-mail so I can discuss this material with you. My e-mail address is: R.Lyons@ieee.org

Comment: @NimitVachhani:  Do you need to analyse the frequency content of your load cell readings, or do you just want a clean number?  If all you need is a clean measurement, then an FFT might not be the right direction to go.  You seem to have a static measurement (load on the load cell remains constant) and want to clean up the noise.  If that is the case, averaging is your first step.  Could you explain a little more about what your measurements mean?

Comment: @JRE Greetings JRE... Well the values are static as the load applied was not changed. Now my main aim is to get stable readings with higher accuracy, next is to apply some kind of vibration suppressing filters so that even in the presence of vibrations readings don't change much. Third graph posted in my question is of the fft after removing dc bias and first graph is of fft with dc bias.

Comment: If all you want is to remove noise, then the FFT is the wrong way to go.  Take the average of all your points and you are done.  Take an average of more points if it is still too noisy.

Comment: @Nimit. Based on the title of your post I thought you wanted to compute a meaningful spectral plot of your signal. But if JRE is correct and all you want to do is smooth (attenuate the amplitude fluctuations of) your constant-amplitude (DC) signal, then pass your signal through a narrowband lowpass digital filter that has a gain of one at zero Hz (DC). If you need guidance on how to do that, let us know.

Comment: @RichardLyons sure please help me. The main reason for plotting fft is to see the noisy frequency and remove them. I am totally new to DSP and signal smoothing, so I thought that fft is the right step to start with

Comment: @RichardLyons please help me in constructing low pass narrow band filter

Answer (score 0):

@Nimit. I recommend that you study and learn to design and implement what are called 2nd-order IIR lowpass filters. Once you thoroughly understand such filters you should design a 2nd-order IIR lowpass filter, that has unity gain at zero Hz, and experiment by applying your noisy signal to that filter and see how much noise reduction is achieved. Then you should apply your noisy signal to a cascade of two identical 2nd-order IIR lowpass unity-gain filters and see how much noise reduction is achieved. Finally you should apply your noisy signal to a cascade of three identical 2nd-order IIR lowpass unity-gain filters and see how much noise reduction is achieved. Nimit, you have much experimenting to do.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for note. I think unit gain at zero means 0 HZ should be my cut off frequency, correct ? And what should be my sampling frequency? Should it be the sampling frequency of my ADC ?

Comment: @Nimit. If you send me a private e-mail, and if you're able to send me an electronic file of your 500 time-domain samples (your 500 "readings"), I can help you. My e-mail address is: R dot Lyons at ieee dot org.

Comment: sure I will do it.